# Can i put everything back after accidentally doing "apt-get remove mysql-server"?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, mysql, database

I have accidentally typed in webserver terminal following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 php* mysql* -y
```

Can i rescue my database tables, without a backup? I know that, for instance, apache does not remove anything (configs) from system on removal,  but what about mysql?

Comment: Removing mysql packages should not have affected your mysql data files.

Comment: i know that each time you run "apt-get install mysql-server" it creates new database with new root password.

Comment: Usually `apt-get remove` is supposed not to touch any configuration files while uninstalling packages. But I don't use mysql and can't tell you if that one has anything special on it...

Comment: Then you **should not** write this ( i noticed before that i *know* it creates *new* database in "install" that's why i am asking and not trying "install" again). Thanks.

Comment: You might want to have a look in the directory `/var/lib/mysql/` to check if the databases files are still there.

Comment: An addition to below answers, you can get list of mysql configuration files,  using `more /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql*.conffiles` , make a *backup* of configuration files & databases before trying reinstalling it, as safety measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still can fetch for your database files within:

> /var/lib/mysql

To access a `database_name_1` you previously created, you'll find its path as:

> /var/lib/mysql/database_name_1

(you'll need `su` permissions obviously)

Comment: Good. But how can i restore it, if "install" creates new database?

Comment: you know the location: so you can copy those DB files wherever you want to save them. Later if you install LAMP, you can import those DB files without needing to recreate them again

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get` **does not** delete data files when you remove a package. It might remove *configuration* files if you instruct it to `purge` (but that's not default behavior).

By default, mysql databases reside in `/var/lib`. Your dbs should be there.